# Webview crashing with android11

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, android-webview, android-11

I have webview implemented in kotlin. webview crashes when it reloads url. I have `androidx.webkit:webkit:1.6.1` and android system `webview(106.xx.xx.xx)` on android 11. The build is working on android 7 google webview(when it used to be google webview).
Please see the error below.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/frUNt.png)

I could not do anything since the crash report doesnt seem to help

Comment: Please include full error text and stack trace as text (not mage) in your question.